# Online meeting using Microsoft graph api sdk

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We create an online meeting in azure bot (in teams) using microsoft graph api sdk. We have agent(Customer care executive) and enduser scenarios. When an agent creates an online meeting it adds agent and enduser in the meeting and additionally it adds a person in the meeting as an Organizer whose account is used to create GraphClient api token. We have multiple agents, whenever agents create the meeting the organizer gets notification in his teams account. So he receives multiple notification per day, so how to stop sending notification to an organizer or how to remove the organizer in the meeting.

```
// creating object for GraphServiceClient 
private GraphServiceClient _graphDelegatedServiceClient;
 IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                         .Create(_graphAccessCredentials.ClientId)
                         .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                         .Build();

                        _delegatedAuthProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication);
                        _graphDelegatedServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_delegatedAuthProvider);

// create online meeting
var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    EndDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                    Subject = DataManager.ApplicationSettings[BotConstants.TEAMS_MEETING_SUBJECT]
                };

               onlineMeeting.Participants = new MeetingParticipants
                    {
                        Organizer = new MeetingParticipantInfo
                        {
                            Identity = new IdentitySet
                            {
                                User = new Identity
                                {
                                    Id ="23i29eqdnsk" //Agent AD id
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };

 OnlineMeeting meeting = await _graphDelegatedServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
                                              .Request().
                                              WithUsernamePassword(_graphAccessCredentials.Username, _graphAccessCredentials.Password)
                                              .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```